# Get IANA time zone from address

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How can I get IANA time zone from address? For example, if I have address 409 East Wilson Ave. Staten Island, NY 10306, is there a library that will output "America/New_York" which I would than use to convert UTC timestamp to "America/New_York" local timestamp?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Off the top of my head you will need data/geo-location API to convert a street address to lat/long coordinates, and then probably access to other data/API that can convert lat/lang to the closest relevant timezone. Which of these are you struggling with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates)